# What is the issue in my code?

Tags: android, image, class, android-framelayout

I am working on an application in which I am using a frame layout. In the frame layout there are three classes as follows:

1. creating image
2. checking the pixel of the image the user touches
3. drawing the image

But when I am touching on the same color, it is giving me a different color value. If anyone wants to see my [code](http://codepad.org/jYkpqxQo) then it is there. If you want to check which image is used by me then the images are as follows:

[image]

the second image which is used for getting the pixel:
[image]

Can any one tell me why it is not giving me correct value of the color on touch on the image 
?
**Edited1**
my edited code of the imagein class is as follow [code after editing[4](http://codepad.org/1Tbl7wFk)

Comment: I think you may want to explain in more detail what you're expecting and what is happening instead.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel is right -based on your previous questions-: you should look up how to translate your on-screen coordinates to match your picture coordinates.

Comment: @rekaszeru can you explain me one more time ?

Comment: @rekaszeru can we chat on this question ?

Comment: @rekaszeru i have changes my code for the bitmap for which i am checking the pixel but it is also not working .....  can you help me on this/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are making assumptions based on the the pixel coordinates of the image, and not translating the coordinates as they exist once Android resizes your art.  You should see what Android thinks the image size is, after it's drawn to your View and make sure that the spot you're touching is the same spot that you're expecting to be touching.

Comment: when user touch on the  same color spot then it should display same color  but it dispalying me other value

Comment: iam overlapping same image on the other so it will give me the same position na

Comment: but the x,y that you're touching... the actual coordinate that the tablet (or phone) reports back as being touched... are you SURE that this matches the coordinate on the image? It doesn't matter if the two images are overlapping if the images are both scaled! So you look at it in Photoshop and you say (for instance) 300x300 should be RED, but when you touch it, you're at 340x340 (because it's been scaled) and ANDROID says "that coordinate is blue".  see?

Comment: i have changes my code for the bitmap for which i am checking the pixel but it is also not working .....